# NSPredicate: filtering objects by day of NSDate property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Core Data model with an `NSDate` property. I want to filter the database by day. I assume the solution will involve an `NSPredicate`, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

I know how to compare the day of two `NSDate`s using `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`, but how do I filter it with an `NSPredicate`?

Perhaps I need to create a category on my `NSManagedObject` subclass that can return a bare date with just the year, month and day. Then I could compare that in an `NSPredicate`. Is this your recommendation, or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Given a NSDate * *startDate* and *endDate* and a NSManagedObjectContext * *moc*:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: what if we have only one date?

Comment: Looks like you can use `==`. Though if you're searching by day, remember that NSDate is a date-and-time -- you might want to use a midnight-to-midnight range.

Comment: Example on how to also setup startDate and endDate, see my answer below

Comment: @jlstrecker can u show me an example how to use a midnight to midnight range. for example: i have 2 same days but different timing. and i want to filter by day(i dont care about the timing). How can i do that?

Comment: @Shady In the above example, you could set `startDate` to 2012-09-17 0:00:00 and `endDate` to 2012-09-18 0:00:00 and the predicate to startDate <= date < endDate. That would catch all times on 2012-09-17.

Comment: @diciu I'v tried the exactly same predicate as yours:

@"(startDate >= %@) AND (startDate <= %@)", self.minDate, self.maxDate]"

but i'm still getting the error!
'Unable to parse the format string "(startDate >= 2014-07-14 23:46:05 +0000) AND (startDate <= 2014-07-19 12:48:19 +0000)"'

What am I doing wrong here!?? Is the format wrong??

Comment: @MQoder are those NSDates, or strings?

Comment: @quellish the "startDate" is a NSDate object. What I did wrong was passing a string to the predicate instead of creating te predicate on the fly. I solved it by using NSCompoundPredicate.

Comment: My dates are in Swift 3 native format (value type `Date`), so I had to use `as NSDate` to silence a compiler error.

Answer (score 64):

Example on how to also set up startDate and endDate to the above given answer:

```
...

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
//create a date with these components
NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setDay:0]; //reset the other components
[components setYear:0]; //reset the other components
NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDate options:0];
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((date >= %@) AND (date < %@)) || (date = nil)",startDate,endDate];

...
```

Here I was searching for all entries within one month. It's worth to mention, that this example also shows how to search 'nil' date-entires.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3.0 extension for Date:

```
extension Date{

func makeDayPredicate() -> NSPredicate {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self)
    components.hour = 00
    components.minute = 00
    components.second = 00
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: components)
    components.hour = 23
    components.minute = 59
    components.second = 59
    let endDate = calendar.date(from: components)
    return NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day =< %@", argumentArray: [startDate!, endDate!])
}
}
```

Then use like:

```
 let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyObject")
 fetchReq.predicate = myDate.makeDayPredicate()
```

Answer (score 10):

In Swift I got something similar to:

```
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(predicate)
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
        let components = calendar!.components(
            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |
                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth |
                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay |
                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour |
                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute |
                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date!)
        components.hour = 00
        components.minute = 00
        components.second = 00
        let startDate = calendar!.dateFromComponents(components)
        components.hour = 23
        components.minute = 59
        components.second = 59
        let endDate = calendar!.dateFromComponents(components)
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day =< %@", argumentArray: [startDate!, endDate!])
```

I had a hard time to discover that string interpolation `"\(this notation)"` doesn't work for comparing dates in NSPredicate.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Swift 3 version added below.

Answer (score 8):

I ported the answer from [Glauco Neves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484150/133166) to Swift 2.0 and wrapped it inside a function that receives a date and returns the `NSPredicate` for the corresponding day:

```
func predicateForDayFromDate(date: NSDate) -> NSPredicate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let components = calendar!.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
    components.hour = 00
    components.minute = 00
    components.second = 00
    let startDate = calendar!.dateFromComponents(components)
    components.hour = 23
    components.minute = 59
    components.second = 59
    let endDate = calendar!.dateFromComponents(components)

    return NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day =< %@", argumentArray: [startDate!, endDate!])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Swift 3 version added below.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Rafael's answer (incredibly useful, thank you!), porting for Swift 3.

```
func predicateForDayFromDate(date: Date) -> NSPredicate {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
    components.hour = 00
    components.minute = 00
    components.second = 00
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: components)
    components.hour = 23
    components.minute = 59
    components.second = 59
    let endDate = calendar.date(from: components)

    return NSPredicate(format: "YOUR_DATE_FIELD >= %@ AND YOUR_DATE_FIELD =< %@", argumentArray: [startDate!, endDate!])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the previous answers, an update and alternative method using Swift 5.x

```
func predicateForDayUsingDate(_ date: Date) -> NSPredicate {
    
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    // following creates exact midnight 12:00:00:000 AM of day
    let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
    // following creates exact midnight 12:00:00:000 AM of next day
    let endOfDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startOfDay)!
    
    return NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day < %@", argumentArray: [startOfDay, endOfDay])
}
```

If you'd prefer to create the time for `endOfDay` as 11:59:59 PM, you can instead include...

```
    let endOfDayLessOneSecond = endOfDay.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-1))
```

but then you might change the NSPredicate to...

```
    return NSPredicate(format: "day >= %@ AND day <= %@", argumentArray: [startOfDay, endOfDayLessOneSecond])
```

...with specific note of the change from `day < %@` to `day <= %@`.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently spent some time attempting to solve this same problem and add the following to the list of alternatives to prepare start and end dates (includes updated method for iOS 8 and above)...

```
NSDate *dateDay = nil;
NSDate *dateDayStart = nil;
NSDate *dateDayNext = nil;

dateDay = <<USER_INPUT>>;

dateDayStart = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:dateDay];

//  dateDayNext EITHER
dateDayNext = [dateDayStart dateByAddingTimeInterval:(24 * 60 * 60)];

//  dateDayNext OR
NSDateComponents *dateComponentDay = nil;
dateComponentDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponentDay setDay:1];
dateDayNext = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponentDay
                                                            toDate:dateDayStart
                                                           options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
```

...and the `NSPredicate` for the Core Data `NSFetchRequest` (as already shown above in other answers)...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateAttribute >= %@) AND (dateAttribute < %@)", dateDayStart, dateDayNext]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    //create a date with these components
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [components setMonth:0];
    [components setDay:0]; //reset the other components
    [components setYear:0]; //reset the other components
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDate options:0];

    startDate = [NSDate date];
    endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)];//change here

    NSString *startTimeStamp = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:floor([endDate timeIntervalSince1970])] stringValue];
    NSString *endTimeStamp = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:floor([startDate timeIntervalSince1970])] stringValue];


   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((paidDate1 >= %@) AND (paidDate1 < %@))",startTimeStamp,endTimeStamp];
    NSLog(@"predicate is %@",predicate);
    totalArr = [completeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [self filterAndPopulateDataBasedonIndex];
    [self.tableviewObj reloadData];
    NSLog(@"result is %@",totalArr);
```

I have filtered array from current date to 7 days back. I mean I am getting one week data from current date. This should work.

Note: I am converting date which is coming with milli seconds by 1000, and comparing after. Let me know if you need any clarity.

Comment: In your answer `completeArray` is it having Array of `dictionary` or `dataModel` 
I want to apply on DataModel.