# Determining if an NSDate is today in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I've tried multiple methods and tried some suggestions on this site, but how can I determine if a CoreData attribute "dueDate" is equal to "Today", I know NSDate is a specific time as well but I want the predicate to return if it is the same day/month/year regardless of what the time is in the day. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with:

```
- (NSPredicate *)matchAttribute:(NSString *)attributeName withDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneDay.day = 1;

    NSDate *lastMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDate *nextMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:lastMidnight options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];

    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K >= %@) AND (%K <= %@)", attributeName, lastMidnight, attributeName, nextMidnight];
}
```

Inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364495/nspredicate-for-finding-events-that-occur-between-a-certain-date-range), [here](http://zdam.posterous.com/core-data-fetch-by-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965331/nspredicate-filtering-objects-by-day-of-nsdate-property).

Comment: Although this works, it should be changed to allow for end of month scenarios. Use options:0 instead of NSWrapCalendarComponents or you'll get 07-01-2014 when checking an end of month date such as 07-31-2014 rather than the expected 08-01-2014. NSDate *nextMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:lastMidnight options:0];

Comment: What @MarkMcCorkle said is actually really important or it won't work in end of month !!!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by using NSDateComonents and NSCalendar.

Just created NSDateComponents of just day/month/year from the original NSDate and then re-created it to a date using dateFromComponents.

This lead to it being the start of the day, I then created another date using the method above that was the start of "tomorrow" and used > and < to see if it was "today." Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: This effectively does the same as using using NSDateFormatter which is also locale aware. In either solution, enable the "Indexed" flag on the "dueDate" attribute to help avoid testing all of the Entities against the predicate. (more important as the number of managed objects if you are dealing with increases)

Answer (score 1):

The concept of today is tricky because what do you mean by it?  That is why it is not straightforward.  Do you mean as in the same day, month and year regardless of timezone?  Do you mean within the same 24 hour period?  Within the last 24 hours?  It can get complicated.

Your answer to the above determines the answer to your question.  If it is the same day, month and year then use NSDateComponents to extract those three values and compare them.  If you mean within 24 hours then you can use the date method `-timeIntervalSinceDate:` to determine the number of seconds between the dates.

If you mean something else then please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift Answer

I use [AFDateHelper](https://github.com/melvitax/AFDateHelper)
If you don't want to use third party. Just go check the source to find implementation of `dateAtStartOfDay()` and `dateAtEndOfDay()`

Then its a breeze.

`NSPredicate(format: "pickup_time > %@ && pickup_time < %@",NSDate().dateAtStartOfDay(),NSDate().dateAtEndOfDay())`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things that you might want to try.

1. Add another integer attribute, dueDateYYYMMDD to your entity. Convert the NSDate using NSDateFormatter to the YYYYMMDD string, then use NSString integerValue to produce the dueDateYYYYMMDD.
2. Use NSDateFormatter on [NSDate date] to produce "today" in YYYYMMDD format and [NSString integerValue] to obtain "today" as an integer (todayInt). Now your predicate can be easily constructed to compare  dueDateYYYYMMDD == todayInt.

Comparison on integer values is more efficient than strings.

Comment: And what if today means within 24 hours?  Or the last 24 hours?  What about timezones?

Comment: Fair question. A day is an imprecise measurement of time. comparisons are only useful when using the same unit of measurement; be it time, money, mass or volume.

Answer (score 0):

You might find Erica Sadun NSDate utilities helpful for this kind of thing.

Lot's of really handy bits and pieces. Check it out.

https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions

Matt