# NSPredicate for multiday-all day event

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, nspredicate, fetch

In my database i have two columns i.e. startDate and endDate and if user pressed any date in UI like 16July 2015 then it should fetch all events which fall between startDate and endDate.

Earlier I wrote a predicate for fetching staring events:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ >= %%@ AND %@ < %%@", @"startTime", @"endTime"], date, [date dateForNextDay]]
```

But above query will not work if given date is not a event's starting date.

Example:
 If i have a conference date as 7/13 - 7/16 and given date is 7/14 then conference event should be able to fetch using predicate. My old query will only work on 7/13. It should fetch that event on given dates - 7/13, 7/14, 7/15, 7/16

Comment: Can you clarify the phrase "fetch all events which fall between startDate and endDate"?  Do you really mean "all events for which the selected date falls between the startDate and endDate" ?

Comment: @danh If i have a conference date as 7/13 - 7/16 and lets say today is 7/14 then conference event should be able to fetch in predicate. My old query will only work on 7/13. It should fetch that event on given dates - 7/13, 7/14, 7/15, 7/16

Comment: Can you present dateForNextDay code?  Shouldn't it just be date, date?

Comment: NextDay is nothing just next day.. [dayOffsetComponents setDay:1]

Comment: I see.  You must have read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8435736/294949 which handles the edge case of a midnight end time.  It's good, but I think you were confused by the code in it, which is solving a different problem "finding events within a range", you are finding events that contain a single date.  Even the language in your question has that confusion (see my first comment).  Added an answer accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch events where a given date is greater than or equal to and less than or equal to a given date....

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= startTime AND %@ <= endTime", date, date]
```

**EDIT...**  Testing this with a simple object confirms that it works correctly....

```
- (NSArray *)filterArray:(NSArray *)array forDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= startTime AND %@ <= endTime", date, date];
    return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
}

- (void)testPredicate {

    NSDictionary *event0 = @{ @"startTime":[self dateFromString:@"07/01/2015"], @"endTime":[self dateFromString:@"07/04/2015"] };
    NSDictionary *event1 = @{ @"startTime":[self dateFromString:@"07/10/2015"], @"endTime":[self dateFromString:@"07/14/2015"] };
    NSDictionary *event2 = @{ @"startTime":[self dateFromString:@"08/02/2015"], @"endTime":[self dateFromString:@"08/09/2015"] };

    NSArray *events = @[event0, event1, event2];

    NSDate *july9 = [self dateFromString:@"07/09/2015"];
    NSDate *july10 = [self dateFromString:@"07/10/2015"];
    NSDate *july11 = [self dateFromString:@"07/11/2015"];
    NSDate *july13 = [self dateFromString:@"07/13/2015"];
    NSDate *july14 = [self dateFromString:@"07/14/2015"];
    NSDate *july15 = [self dateFromString:@"07/15/2015"];

    NSLog(@"filtered using 9 should be empty %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july9]);
    NSLog(@"filtered using 10 should hit %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july10]);
    NSLog(@"filtered using 11 should hit %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july11]);
    NSLog(@"filtered using 13 should hit %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july13]);
    NSLog(@"filtered using 14 should hit %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july14]);
    NSLog(@"filtered using 15 should be empty %@", [self filterArray:events forDate:july15]);
}

- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

The foregoing doesn't require special handling for the midnight case in order to perform as the question suggests (inclusive of the last endTime).

This generates the following log output which you can confirm for yourself...

```
filtered using 9 should be empty ()
filtered using 10 should hit (
        {
        endTime = "2015-07-14 07:00:00 +0000";
        startTime = "2015-07-10 07:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
filtered using 11 should hit (
        {
        endTime = "2015-07-14 07:00:00 +0000";
        startTime = "2015-07-10 07:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
filtered using 13 should hit (
        {
        endTime = "2015-07-14 07:00:00 +0000";
        startTime = "2015-07-10 07:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
filtered using 14 should hit (
        {
        endTime = "2015-07-14 07:00:00 +0000";
        startTime = "2015-07-10 07:00:00 +0000";
    }
)
filtered using 15 should be empty ()
```

Comment: This code is also returning me all future events including event on given date.

Comment: @Tariq please see edit demonstrating the code works as expected in a simple test.  Perhaps your app is in error elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have two dates : date and dateForNextDay.

I think you should try this :
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startTime >= %@ && %@ < endTime", date, [date dateForNextDay]];

Or just switch yours last *%@* and *%%@* like this => *@"%@ >= %%@ AND %%@ < %@"*

Edit: And btw, as [@danh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh) said, may be you just want to use date, date.

Edit2: Ok, I answered too quickly, the all condition was false, and danh was right again ;)
@"startTime <= %@ && %@ <= endTime"

Comment: Didnt worked for me. It returned all current and future events instead of events in a given range. If given date is 16July then result should return events which comes in the range of startDate - endDate