# Can I create a predicate based on the properties of child class objects?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two classes: Activity and Action. Activity is the parent class, Action are the child, this is a one to many relationship. In setting up a NSFetchedResultsController I would like to set a predicate based the properties of the child class. Here's an example...

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "filter only activities that have actions which have their date property equalling today")
```

If I were to filter the activities using a for in loop, this is what it would look like...

```
for activity in activities
{
    if activity.actions != nil
    {
        for action in activity.actions
        {
            if action.date == today
            {
                // add activity to filtered array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SUBQUERY` in your `NSPredicate`. Here I used an `NSArray` as a demonstration.

```
let today = Date()

let array: NSArray = [
    Activity(actions: [
        Action(date: today)
        ]),
    Activity(actions: [
        Action(date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))
        ])
]

// here is your predicate
let result = array.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(actions, $action, $action.date == %@) .@count > 0", today as CVarArg))
print(result.count) // 1
```

Note that I used `==` here to compare the dates, which means it will only match if the date is *exactly* equal to `today`. If by "today" you meant "any time in the 24 hours", then you would have to use the answer suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168374/determining-if-an-nsdate-is-today-in-nspredicate):

```
func getLastAndNextMidnight(date: Date) -> (Date, Date) {
    let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
    var oneDay = DateComponents()
    oneDay.day = 1
    let lastMidnight = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: oneDay, to: lastMidnight)!
    return (lastMidnight, nextMidnight)
}
let midnights = getLastAndNextMidnight(date: today)
let result = array.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(actions, $action, ($action.date >= %@) AND ($action.date <= %@)) .@count > 0", midnights.0 as CVarArg, midnights.1 as CVarArg))
print(result.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any action today?. Predicate format:

```
"ANY actions.date == today"
```

Comment: I believe this would work for the example above. However, if I needed to verify more than one property I would have to use a subquery. That solution seems to be more flexible.