# CoreData conditionally fetching on NSDate using NSPredicate (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

Basically I have an entity called TimeLoc that has three attributes: time, latitude and longitude. And their types are Date, Double and Double respectively. I got stuck when I was trying to make a request with filter on attribute time.

Here is my code:

```
...
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate) 
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TimeLoc")
var endTime = NSDate()
var startTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -65)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "time>= \(startTime) AND time<= \(endTime)")
request.predicate = predicate
var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
...
```

And I got the following error:
'Unable to parse the format string "time>= 2015-07-14 03:24:03 +0000 AND time<= 2015-07-14 03:25:08 +0000"'

How should I fix this? I have googled a bit but all the solutions I found were in Objective-C. It would be great if someone can answer me in Swift.

Edit: As V-Xtreme suggested, an answer to this problem can be find in Glauco Neves's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965331/nspredicate-filtering-objects-by-day-of-nsdate-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are sending parameters to the predicate in NSDate format :

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "time>= \(startTime) AND time<= \(endTime)")
```

Here your startTime and endTime is of type NSDate . Try to convert it in String format and pass it to the predicate . It should work .

Reference : [NSPredicate: filtering objects by day of NSDate property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965331/nspredicate-filtering-objects-by-day-of-nsdate-property)

Comment: Thank you@V-Xtreme. I tried `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "time>= '\(startTime)' AND time<= '\(endTime)'")`. But I got a new error, '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb889fd6dc0'.

Comment: It solved the 'Unable to parse the format string' error. But got a more confusing error. please see the first comment, I edited it. @V-Xtreme.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution did not work for me, though it made intuitive sense. As an alternative, I created a predicate so search a range, like so:

`"%K BETWEEN {%@, %@}"` where `%K` is my key path, and the two `%@`s are my start and end dates.

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BETWEEN {%@, %@}", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Activity.startTime), startDate!.startOfDay, endDate!.endOfDay])
```