# NSPredicate with NSDate in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, nsdate

I'm currently trying to set up a fetch request to retrieve events from a certain date range (starting with comparing just one date). After trying to create a NSPredicate with different variations of  <=, => ,BETWEEN  etc.  which all did not work I spotted a possibly strange behaviour:
My current NSPredicate looks like this :

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "start>= %@",dayBegin);
```

where dayBegin is set to NSDate();

However when printing the predicate I get:

```
start >= CAST(475632000.000000, "NSDate")
```

Evaluating the date above with

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(ti));
```

converts to yesterday, 31 ago.

The result is as expected, all dates in my calendar are shown (since all are above that date).

Trying the solution proposed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397408/coredata-conditionally-fetching-on-nsdate-using-nspredicate-swift) I experience the following parsing error:

```
'Unable to parse the format string "start>= 2016-01-28 00:00:00 +0000"'
```

I have also tried comparing the date as a time interval using %d but it  didn't work as well.
Any ideas whats going wrong?

**Solved:**

I was using an Accessor to modify the dates like this:

```
var startDate: NSDate?{
    get {
        return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: start);
        }
    set(d){
        start = d!.timeIntervalSince1970;
    }
}
```

Hence I always stored the days with the wrong reference days and did not notice That it refers to 1st of January 2001 instead of 1970.
Now Im using this Accessor:

```
var startDate: NSDate?{
    get {
    return NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: start);
    }
    set(d){
        start = d!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the device date set to? how did you create the dates in the data store?

Comment: im testing in simulator whose date is set to today. But on the device I get the same results. I Populated the dates like this:  start = date.timeIntervalSince1970;
The Managed Properties are from Type NSTimeInterval and the dates can be retrieved correctly

Comment: Note that Core Data stores the time interval since the *refence date* (Jan 1, 2001 GMT), and that is what the value 475632000.000000 shows, it corresponds to `2016-01-28 00:00:00 +0000`.

Comment: Oh, so I assume Im storing  and retrieving the dates the wrong way , i did not encounter that

Comment: `start = date.timeIntervalSince1970` is wrong. As explained in the "duplicate", it should be `start = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.