# Filter by day from NSDate in Realm, Swift

Tags: swift, filter, realm

So, I put `NSDate` in Realm model:

```
class GeneralList: Object {
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    dynamic var notes = ""
}
```

How to get, for example, all 'notes' in 27.03.2016 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I find easy way:

1. Create public extension for String and create function with separate NSDate:

   ```
    public static func sepaDate(whatNeed: String) -> String  {
    var currentDate = NSDate()
   let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

   let dateComponents = calendar!.components([.Day, .Month, .Year, .Minute, .Hour], fromDate: currentDate)
       var forReturn: String = "0"
       switch whatNeed {
           case "day":
               let valu = String(dateComponents.day)
               forReturn = valu
           case "month":
           let valu = String(dateComponents.month)
           forReturn = valu
           case "year":
           let valu = String(dateComponents.year)
           forReturn = valu
           case "hour":
           let valu = String(dateComponents.hour)
           forReturn = valu
           case "minute":
           let valu = String(dateComponents.minute)
           forReturn = valu
           default: print("Error")
       }
       return forReturn
   }
   }
   ```
2. In Realm class, create separate date:

   ```
   dynamic var minute = String.sepaDate("minute")
   dynamic var hour = String.sepaDate("hour")
   dynamic var day = String.sepaDate("day")
   dynamic var month = String.sepaDate("month")
   dynamic var year = String.sepaDate("year")
   ```
3. In ViewController call to predicate

   ```
    let dayday = String(dateComponents.day)
            let monthmonth = String(dateComponents.month)
            let yearyear = String(dateComponents.year)
           let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "day = %@ AND month = %@ AND year = %@", dayday, monthmonth, yearyear)
           generalRecords = uiRealm.objects(GeneralList).filter(predicate)
   ```

I hope it's help somebody...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this function, from [Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133166/rafael)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268028/5387501)

```
private func createMessageRealmModelFromIncomingMessage(incomingMessage: MessageRestModel) -> MessageRealmModel {
    let messageRealmModel = MessageRealmModel()

    messageRealmModel.id = incomingMessage.id!
    messageRealmModel.messageType = "CHAT_MESSAGE"
    messageRealmModel.value = (incomingMessage.content?.value)!
    messageRealmModel.senderId = incomingMessage.senderId!
    messageRealmModel.recipientId = incomingMessage.recipientId!
    messageRealmModel.sendDate = incomingMessage.sendDate!
    messageRealmModel.serverDeliveryDate = incomingMessage.serverDeliveryDate!
    messageRealmModel.receiverDeliveryDate = NSDate().msFromEpoch()

    return messageRealmModel
}
```

And then use it as a parameter for Realm's `filter` function like this:

```
var c = NSDateComponents()
c.year = 2016
c.month = 3
c.day = 27

var date = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)?.dateFromComponents(c)

let generalListsInDay = realm.objects(GeneralList).filter(self.predicateForDayFromDate(day))
```

After executing this code your `generalListsInDay` should contain all `GeneralList`'s in 27.03.2016