# How to query a date property in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm database with an object "Events" with a property name "occasion" of type string, a property name "venue" of type string and the other one is "date" of type Date(). 
My question is how do we query the occasions which have a date the same as today (current day). I have tried this code to retrieve the occasions using the date filter and it does work:

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
// dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)        

todayEvent = realm.objects(Events.self).filter("date = '\(stringDate)'").sorted(byKeyPath: "venue", ascending: true)
```

The date in the Realm database shows a date in this format "17 Jan 2019 at 12:00:00 AM" even when the date was saved in the format of dd/MM/yyyy.   I've tried changing the date format but still, it won't work. Or do I need to set a format for the date property when I declare it in the first place? If so how do I do this in a Realm class object? I've tried but it gave an error. I'm stuck here now. Please help

This is how I saved the data to Realm database :

```
@IBAction func addNewEventButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {



    let newDataEntry = Events()

    newDataEntry.occasion = occasionTextFile.text!


    let dateString =  dateTextField.text!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    newDataEntry.date = dateFromString!

    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(newDataEntry)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving data \(error)")
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what is your question ? Is the problem in saving date in your format ? or how to retrieve it ?

Comment: please show us how do you save date property of realm object

Comment: Sorry if I’m not clear enough. The problem is in retrieving the data using the query. And I don’t know why the date changed format when saved in realm although save in a different format ie dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: ok. Please update your question and show us how you save an realm object with date property in it

Comment: I've shown the case for saving in realm database  in the edited question.

Comment: what is inside of `dateString` ?

Comment: dateString is a string of date from a DatePicker. DatePicker is also set in format of dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) (emphasis mine):

> The comparison operators ==, <=, <, >=, >, !=, and BETWEEN are
>   supported for Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Float, Double and **Date**
>   property types

Thus, the following should work:

```
let date = Date()
todayEvent = realm.objects(Events.self)
    .filter("date == %@", date)
    .sorted(byKeyPath: "venue") // sorted in ascending order by default
```

Comment: I used your code again. Now the app started normally and did not crashed. However I still did not get the result of the query displayed in the table.

Comment: I put a print statement for “todayEvent” to findout whether the code was called in the load func, the console states “Optional(Results<Events> <0x7f9a1754d9f0>. I dont know whether it is a usefulI info but I hope this would help to solve the matter.

Comment: Just to update. When I just make a normal query without the filter in the syntax, the table displays all the available data including the dates. If I put the filter in the query syntax so that the result would show only the event which has the same date as current day, the table return empty. So it must be the syntax. At least that is what Im thinking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965216/10784781. Found the answer here. Now trying to set the query to “tomorrow”.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Date` object which is with time & locale, so to use only with date can use below function for removing time & locale from date object:

```
   func reomveTimeFrom(date: Date) -> Date {
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
            let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
            return date!
        }
```

Now use this function to get exact date object & fetch data from `realm` database.

```
let today = self.reomveTimeFrom(date: Date())
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date ==  %@",today as NSDate)
let results = realm.objects(Events.self).filter(predicate)
```

Complete [source code on github](https://github.com/rockyy/Swift-Realm-Date)

Comment: @DávidPásztor- update syntax for swift, previous one was for react-native.

Comment: Rocky and Dan Karbayev, I have tried both codes and the app crashed with the following message in the console: Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘invalid value’, reason: ‘Expected object of type date for property ‘date’ on object of type ‘Events’, but received: 19/01/2019’. I did not even have the chance to enter any date when the app crashed. Where did this “19/01/2019” come from?

Comment: @halim - share your schema for `Events` table.

Comment: Events class using Realm database has 3 properties. 1. occasions of type String  2. venue of type String  3. date of type Date().

Comment: @Rocky Thank you but the app still crash when I run it using the new codes. I’m using Dan Karbayev version now. Though the app run it still wont display the result of the query in my tableview

Comment: @halim you can get woking copy of full source code on Github link.

Comment: I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965216/10784781  Thank you bery much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're storing Date objects but trying to filter that property as a string.

This line

```
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

creates a Date() object from a string and that's what's stored in your Realm property.

A Realm date object looks like this

```
2019-01-18T05:00:00.000Z
```

Here's your filter:

```
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
todayEvent = realm.objects(Events.self).filter("date = '\(stringDate)'")
```

This is creating a string from a date object and Realm won't know what to do with it. If you want to filter a date property, use a date object to do so.

Importantly though - that line should crash with the following error

```
Expected object of type date for property 'date' on object of type 'Event', but received: 18 Jan 2019
```

The solution is that if the property your searching on is a Date, then the filter needs to be a Date object.

So an example of writing a date object that starts as a mm/dd/yyyy string

```
let aDateString = "01/20/2019"
let mmddyyyyFormatter = DateFormatter()
mmddyyyyFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
if let dateObjectToStore = mmddyyyyFormatter.date(from: aDateString) {
    newDataEntry.date = dateObjectToStore
} else {
    print("could not create date object")
}
```

Suppose we now want to find that object with a string of "yyyymmdd"

```
let dateStringToFind = "20190120"
let yyyymmddFormatter = DateFormatter()
yyyymmddFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
let dateObjectToFind = yyyymmddFormatter.date(from: dateStringToFind)
let results = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("date == %@", dateObjectToFind)
if results.count > 0 {
    for myObject in results {
        print(myObject)
    }
} else {
    print("no objects have that date")
}
```

as you can see, we stored a date as a date object and then when filtering, filtered for a date object.

There are some caveats to filtering and some exceptions but you get the general idea.