# how to create a predicate that accesses to an object property inside an Array

Tags: objective-c, predicate

Let's suppose I have an NSArray of Person objects, those are composed of 2 properties( name and age ).
Just for the sake of understanding how it works and practice I would like to know how to create a predicate that accesses every member of the array and filters all the objects with an age property that its bigger or equal to 30.
I just can't figure that out:

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@">= 30"];

    [persons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@",persons)
```

What should I type on predicateWithFormat?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPredicate: filtering objects by day of NSDate property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965331/nspredicate-filtering-objects-by-day-of-nsdate-property)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The predicate format is `key` - `operator` - `value` for example

   ```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age >= 30"];
   ```

   or with placeholders

   ```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K >= %ld", @"age", 30];
   ```
2. `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns a new array

   ```
   NSArray *filteredArray = [persons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
   NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray)
   ```

For further information read [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and suggestions! My problem now is that I don't know actually what to put on predicateWithFormat: to specify that the property"age"its inside an object in the Array. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: NVM looks like it does it automatically for me and searches for the member with the property "age"but how the hell does that work out under the hood?

Comment: What type is `persons`? The code is supposed to work if `persons` (better `people`) is a dictionary or a custom class.